# Dismiss dialogue after configuration is changed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-configchanges

I'm currently writing on a Bluetooth application only allowing the user to work with it in the portait mode. However, there are some other reasons causing confguration changes forcing me to show the user that the Bluetooth connection has been lost.

While connecting to a device I show a dialogue prompting a password. If a configuration change occurs while this dialogue is visible I want to dismiss it. Therefore I call a helper method in `onSaveInstanceState`, `onDestroy` as well as `onCreate` (if the saved instance state is not null).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        this.tryDismiss();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    System.out.println("Saving instance state!");
    this.tryDismiss();

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    System.out.println("Destroying dialogue!");
    this.tryDismiss();

    super.onDestroy();
}

public void tryDismiss()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("DIE BART, DIE!");
        this.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    catch (Exception closingException)
    {
    }
}
```

However, the dialogue is still displayed to the user. I have read a similar questions, but couldn't figure out a solution to this issue.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just call dialog.dismiss() in onPause of your activity

Comment: Thanks, for your advice. However, when the user simply minimizes the application the dialogue is not visible anymore, though the Bluetooth connection and the object referencing to it are still "alive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a strong reference in the activity displaying the dialogue and invoking the `dismiss()` method in the activitie's `onSaveInstanceState`method fixed this issue for me. I know, it's not the most optimal solution, but it works.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle persistantState)
{
    if (this.connectionPasswordDialogue != null)
    {
        this.connectionPasswordDialogue.dismiss();
    }
}
```

With strong reference I mean a private attribute used internally by the activity:

```
private DialogueUserModePassword connectionPasswordDialogue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily `dismiss()` method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Comment: The problem ist that altough invoking the `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` method within my `tryDismiss()` method the dialogue is still visible.